# Start independent job steps and keep track of highest exit code

Tags: bash, job-scheduling, exit-code, slurm

I want to start many independent tasks (job steps) as part of one job and want to keep track of the highest exit code of all these tasks.

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883372/slurm-submit-multiple-tasks-per-node) I am currently doing something like

```
#SBATCH stuf....

for i in {1..3}; do
    srun -n 1 ./myprog ${i} >& task${i}.log &
done

wait
```

in my `jobs.sh`, which I `sbatch`, to start my tasks.

How can I define a variable `exitcode` which, after the wait command, contains the highest exit code of all the tasks?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Any exit code != 0 means error, why only the highest.

Comment: Because I would like to take action based on the value of the highest error code. (I throw these error codes myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store jobs' pids in an array and wait for each one, like this

```
#SBATCH stuf....

for i in {1..3}; do
    srun -n 1 ./myprog ${i} >& task${i}.log &
    pids+=($!)
done

for pid in ${pids[@]}; do
    wait $pid
    exitcode=$[$? > exitcode ? $? : exitcode]
done

echo $exitcode
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GNU parallel to your advantage in such case:

```
#SBATCH stuf....

parallel --joblog ./jobs.log -P 3 "srun -n1 --exclusive ./myprog {} >& task{}.log " ::: {1..3}
```

This will run `srun ./mprog` three times with arguments respectively 1, 2 and 3, and redirect the output to three files names `task1.log`, `task2.log` and `task3.log`, just like your `for`-loop does.

With the `--joblog` option, it will furthermore create a file `jobs.log` that will contain some information about each run, among which is the exit code, in column 7. You can then extract the maximum with

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $7}' jobs.log | sort -n | tail -1
```

Comment: extracting the maximum in awk sounds like a better idea than calling sort and tail to me